# Can I execute azure functions during day time only with specific times

Tags: azure-functions

HI I am trying out azure function.  Basically I want to trigger a function 3 times a day. For example
9:00 AM, 12 PM and 5 PM. This trigger a function that would get data from the database send an email or message on message on Slack?   Can someone guide me?

I am using visual studio 2019, C# and SQL database.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to play with `Cronexpression` for that.

Assuming you want to it run at `09:00 12:00 17:00` everyday during working days alone, then a cronexpresstion of `0 0 9,12,17 * * 1-5` will give you an output with next 5 occurrences as (This answer is being posted on a weekend so the next occurrences during weekdays are below)

```
[01/04/2021 09:00:00+00:00] (01/04/2021 09:00:00Z)
[2021-01-02T12:28:08.938Z] 01/04/2021 12:00:00+00:00 (01/04/2021 12:00:00Z)
[2021-01-02T12:28:08.939Z] 01/04/2021 17:00:00+00:00 (01/04/2021 17:00:00Z)
[2021-01-02T12:28:08.939Z] 01/05/2021 09:00:00+00:00 (01/05/2021 09:00:00Z)
[2021-01-02T12:28:08.940Z] 01/05/2021 12:00:00+00:00 (01/05/2021 12:00:00Z)
```

The cronexpression itself can be configured on the Azure function as

```
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 0 9,12,17 * * 1-5")]TimerInfo myTimer, 
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    }
```

Comment: PS: to add weekend-only trigger, use 0,6